# How do I implement a finance function into this program?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble implementing a function into this program. The program I have currently works fine on its own without the function but I still need to find a way to put `def finance(income, salesPrice):` into it.  I also need to invoke the function with this: `print(finance(income, salesPrice))`. I tried different ways but whenever I try to invoke the function, it says that `income` is not defined.

**This is what I have to make:**

The function will test whether a person is qualified to finance an expensive car. They are qualified if their annual income is greater than $100,000 and the sales price is less than $1,000,000. The function returns a message to the program stating whether the person is qualified or not. The program invokes the finance() function with this print statement: `print (finance (income, salesPrice))` and the user input the income and sales price.

```
def finance(income,salesPrice):
    income = float(input("Please enter annual income: "))
while (income <= 0):
    income = float(input("Invalid input! Please enter positive value: "))
    income += 1

salesPrice = float(input("Please enter sales price of car: "))

if (income>100000 and salesPrice<1000000):
    print("You are qualified to purchase this car.")
else:
    print("You are not qualified to purchase this car.")
result = print(finance(income,salesPrice))
```

Comment: Read up on indentation in Python, it matters.

Comment: Voted to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) + You need to return a variable. **EDIT:** I edited the code based on your problem

```py
def finance(income, sales_price):
    if income > 100000 and sales_price < 1000000:
        return "You are qualified to purchase this car."
    else:
        return "You are not qualified to purchase this car."

salesPrice = float(input("Please enter sales price of car: "))
income = float(input("Please enter annual income: "))
while income <= 0:
    income = float(input("Invalid input! Please enter positive value: "))
    income += 1

print (finance (income, salesPrice))
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the error I was having but now when I run it, the first thing that comes out is asking me for the sales price of the car :/ How can I make it output asking for the annual income?

Comment: @AlexisZ Please give some more details on what type of program you want to make. The reason why it is asking sales price of car first is because It is executed first. The `finance` function will be executed at the last line because the function is called over there.

Comment: This is what I have to do: The function will test whether a person is qualified to finance an expensive car.  They are qualified if their annual income is greater than $100,000 and the sales price is less than $1,000,000. The function returns a message to the program stating whether the person is qualified or not. The program invokes the finance() function with this print statement: “print (finance (income, salesPrice))” and the user input the income and sales price.

Comment: @AlexisZ Thank you very much for the update. Give me a bit of time.

Comment: @AlexisZ I have updated the code. Kindly check it :)

Comment: @AlexisZ Kindly consider marking my answer as solved by clicking the tick to the left of my answer :) I'm really Glad that it helped you

Answer (score 1):

You make an indentation error, your line `while (income <= 0)` is outside of your function, you have to indent it.

More informations about indentation in python [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).